# Changing stylesheet causes qlabel to move

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qlabel

I have a few labels in a horizontal layout, and I want to enable/disable a border around the labels at certain times.  I can do this using stylesheets, but the problem is that every time I enable/disable a border this way, the label shifts left or right in the layout by a few pixels.

This is an annoying artifact that takes away from the look of the UI.  Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Marlon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your labels are on a plain background, then don't enable/disable the borders, just change the border colour to match the background.

Comment: Or if you don't know the background - then "transparent" - it's a valid Qt color.